# Firestore / Angular / Typescript - get value to global variable from subscription of firestore collection

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, collections

How can I save the value depends from subscribe for use it in global scope and other class. I have service in angular:

```
    public maxId: any;
    
      constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
        this.miejscowosciRef = db.collection('miejscowosci', ref => ref.orderBy('id', 'desc'));
      }
    
     getMaxId() {
        this.miejscowosciRef.valueChanges({idField: 'id'})
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.maxId = data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.id > current.id) ? prev : current).id;
          console.log('test 1: ' + this.maxId) // ok.. value is here
        })
        console.log('test 2: ' + this.maxId); // no.. value outside subscribe scope shows undefined
      }
```

I know why it's happen that value is undefined but I have no idea how to save it to global variable or return to other variable.

I want to generate next my own ID for firestore document so I need to know what is value of last one. Maybe there is some other methods for generate next one? I have my own ID: 10001, 10002, 10003 etc. So I have to know the last is 10003 before add new item.

Answer (score 1):

I don't love the idea of self-managed IDs. Ordinarily it is best to let the database (Firestore in this case) handle the creation IDs for documents, as it is less likely to make mistakes (re-using IDs). That said, here's an answer to your question.

---

By using Firestore's `subscribe` method, you are establishing an anonymous listener method to run on every value change. When you call `getMaxId`, you are setting up that listener.

But from the code you have written, it looks like what you want is to return the `maxId` from Firestore. You can get your desired behavior using either method, but you've got to pick one.

If I were you, I would use your subscription and `this.maxId` to refer to the current maximum ID number, which will always be up to date thanks to the listener.

```js
subscribeMaxIdListener() {
  this.miejscowosciRef.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).subscribe(data => {
    this.maxId = data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.id > current.id) ? prev : current).id;

    console.log('New Max ID: ' + this.maxId) // Fires with every value change event
  });

  console.log('Listener Established'); // You should see this only once
}
```

You should call `subscribeMaxIdListener` only once! From then on, `this.maxId` will always have the value you are looking for.

One caveat: if you try to get `this.maxId` before Firestore returns a value to the listener, it will of course be `undefined`. As such, you will want to be careful about when you use it and fail gracefully if Firestore hasn't responded yet.

Comment: But problem is that with this code maxId is undefined outside scope subscribe. I can't get value in other place in service class and in other class. In place where is: "console.log('Listener Established');" maxId is undefined

Comment: Are you referencing `this.maxId` in a sibling method to `subscribeMaxIdListener` within the context of a class? I'm not sure how you are trying to use `this.maxId`, because if "maxId" is a class property, you should have access to it anywhere within the class.

Comment: In other class I have some fields with I have to set depends of data from firestore. Always when I return variable from service its undefined. I don't know how to read from service and set it to variable.

Comment: I see. If you are instantiating your service class with `let service = new ServiceClass( ... )` in these other classes, and you then call `service.subscribeMaxIdListener()`, you should be able to subsequently call `service.maxId` to get the ID you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArticleName: any;
```

---

```
   getNameById(getId):any{
     this.towaryRef.get()
     .subscribe((ss) => {
      ss.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.id == getId) {
          this.ArticleName = doc.data().name
        }
       });
     });
   }
```

And in other class I read from service:

```
this.fsTowaryService.getNameById('10004');
myNazwa = this.fsTowaryService.ArticleName ;
```

I also tried with return function and still the same. I have right data on service but no idea how to save it to global variable.